# Seek field of video node is not working properly

Tags: android, roku, brightscript

I am working on video player using video node of Scene Graph Component. My issue is when i set seek field like 
`m.video.seek = 20` it's start playing from 15 seconds or 18 seconds but not from exact position 20 seconds. My code is...

```
inner = createObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
inner.url = "http://-------------.m3u8"  
inner.streamformat = "hls" 
inner.SwitchingStrategy = "full-adaptation"
```

Video file format is `m3u8` and using `ui_resolutions=fhd` in manifest file of roku app.

Is this issue related to stream format or others? Please help me.

Comment: Are you doing m.video.seek before m.video.control = "play" ?

Comment: Not working#  I think there is no need to set control="play" after setting seek field.

Comment: Sorry! Not working

Comment: Try with some other stream, which is not hosted on the same platform.

Comment: This is a very common thing with Video Players of many devices to start the playBack from a few seconds less than what is set when doing fast-forward or fast-rewind. You would most likely not be able to get to the set seek position in most devices in market, except PCs/Laptops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct behavior you have "hls" streamformat, this is format specific, hls video stream is divided into chunks, so when you set seek, video will start from chunk start not from the middle of this chunk.

Comment: It depends if you can have other url, from the server, streamformat is only used for video decoder to know what type of stream you have.

Comment: Does roku supports pause/resume functionality during video buffering? Im using ".m3u8" file format.

Comment: I haven't tried this, you need to set control="stop" to stop buffering the video

Comment: @ Roman Parashchyn # Only i want to pause the video during buffering and im using video node.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting video component attribute **seekMode** to "accurate"

```
<Video id="videoPlayer" visible="true" translation="[0, 0]" width="1920" height="1080" seekMode = "accurate" enableTrickPlay="true" enableUI="false"/>
```